# Installing Ubuntu 14 - Scrambled screen / display issues

Tags: 14.04, ati, system-installation

When I attempt to boot into Ubuntu 14, I'm able to get all the way into the GUI w/o issue.. but once i'm there, the background is corrupted (black/white stripe/block images) as is anything "inside" a window (the window chrome is fine however).

I CAN see the navigation bar and menu bars, but any dropdown windows are also corrupted. It doesn't matter if I'm booting up to "try" Ubuntu 14, or install it. Complete power-down (vs reboot from windows 8) doesn't seem to make any difference either.

System specs:

- MSI Mainboard, Z77 chipset (onboard Intel gfx disabled in BIOS)
- Core I5-3750K (stock clock), 16GB RAM
- *2x MSI TwinFrozr 7870's (AMD Radeon HD7870's)
- 3x Monitors - 2x ASUS VS239's, 1x Lenovo L2321 (rotated 90 degrees).
- 320GB Samsung SSD
- 2x WD 1TB HDD

*The video cards are NOT in CrossFire mode (bridge is not attached).. actually, there's nothing connected to the second card at all at the moment.

I would attach screenshots for reference.. but I don't have a high enough reputation to do so... You can find them here: [corrupted screen images](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=18AF020DC5DBFA34!70543&authkey=!AFz7GHvityAiPsg&ithint=folder,.jpg)

I'd appreciate any pointers y'all might have. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a graphical-driver issue... wild guess.

Comment: I googled the heck out of this and didn't find anything related to this until AFTER I posted my question.. Karma is a ..well.. Adding "nomodeset" to the boot line got me in. I'm assuming getting the AMD drivers installed after will fix it for good. I'll update once I get past the install.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Intel GPU in BIOS and let Ubuntu use it. It will work flawlessly. However, if you still want to use your Radeon cards, you can try to install proprietary driver (*Dash* -> *Additional Drivers*) but honestly, there is no real reason to do so. There are almost no 3D video games for Linux, and proprietary drivers are often troublemakers especially in dual-GPU setup. In terms of non-gaming use, you don't need the powerful GPU, built-in Intel GPU will do the job.